# How to use Jest/Enzyme to test callback function prop in the child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm currently using react-native with typescript and am struggling with testing child components with jest/enzyme.

I'm currently trying to test the callback function in the prop "updateToDoInput" has been passed to my InputBar component e.g.

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header Title="ToDo App" />
        <InputBar
          todosInput={this.state.todosInput}
          updateToDoInput={(updateInput: string) => this.setState({ todosInput: updateInput })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

For my test I have:

```js
describe('<App /> Component', () => {
 it('renders <InputBar /> with props "todosInput" and "updateToDoInput"', () => {
  
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  
    expect(wrapper
      .contains(<InputBar
        todosInput={wrapper.state("todosInput")}
        updateToDoInput={(updateInput: string) => wrapper.setState({ todosInput: updateInput })}
      />))
      .toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

The tests fails and returns false. I think I'm writing the test for "updateToDoInput" prop wrong.

I'm quite new to testing, how do I test a function with setState passed as props in my child component?

PS. I also tried to use console.log(wrapper.debug()); I get the following output:

```js
      <View style={{...}}>
        <Header Title="ToDo App" />
        <InputBar todosInput="" updateToDoInput={[Function: updateToDoInput]} />
      </View>
```

Not sure what this means, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should consider testing for the functionality. Meaning, invoke the function in your test, and test the result.